# Update database with the userid that submit the form in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form where users can create new employee. I would like to store userid in my db that submit the form.

This is my Controller for creating a new entry:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Employee.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(employee);
    }
```

I have two tables. One for employees and the other one is for the users. As you can see i have **UserID** in my employee table and i would like to store userid that submit the form. I am able to save the form values in my employee table but not able the get the userid. Any idea?

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
}

    [Table("UserProfile")]
     public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is my login form:

```
  <section id="loginForm">
  <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
   @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</fieldset>
  }
   </section>
```

Comment: So is there field in your form like `<input name="UserId" value=123 />` ?

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak No. That user is already logged in. So I would to like to get his userid which is stored in UserProfile table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this below.
I think you are missing couple of things that you can now compare with your own logic.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UsersContext context = new UsersContext();



        string currentUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentUserName))
        {
            currentUserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        var currentUser = (from u in context.UserProfiles
                           where u.UserName.Equals(currentUserName)
                           select u).FirstOrDefault();

        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            context.Employee.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "Mr. Codebased", UserID = currentUser.UserId });
            context.SaveChanges();

            var userProfile = context.Employee.Include("User").FirstOrDefault().User;
        }

    }

    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base()
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public UserProfile User { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, i already have the userid because only registered and loggedin users can submit the form. So I already have the userid in my UserProfile. But i dont know how to get this userid from there and store it into Employee table when that user submit the form.

Comment: Which authentication are you using - form ?

Comment: I added my login form.

Comment: Are you using Form Authentication - Once user has loggedin successfully you should save the userName in the session so that you can refer when required.

Comment: Yes, form authentication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61166/discussion-between-codebased-and-senol-sahin).